# SQL FOR JSON emitting simple arrays

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Using MS SQL Server 2017, I have 2 tables:

- Loan: columns include Loan, OrganizationID
- Organization: columns include OrganizationID

My goal is to produce JSON that includes a string array containing an organization's loan numbers.

I am using SQL along these lines:

```sql
SELECT
    OrganizationID,
    (   SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG('''' + Loan + '''', ',') + ']' 
        FROM Loan 
        WHERE Loan.OrganizationID = Organization.OrganizationID
    ) AS [Loans]
FROM Organization 
WHERE OrganizationID = 1
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

and I would *like to get* this:

```
{
    "OrganizationID": 1,
    "Loans": ['Test 001','Test Loan 123','Test Loan 234']
}
```

However, what I *actually get* wraps the Loans value with quotes:

```
{
    "OrganizationID": 1,
    "Loans": "['Test 001','Test Loan 123','Test Loan 234']"
}
```

I realize I can do this:

```sql
SELECT
    OrganizationID,
    (   SELECT Loan 
        FROM Loan 
        WHERE Loan.OrganizationID = Organization.OrganizationID
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) AS [Loans]
FROM Organization 
WHERE OrganizationID = 1
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

to produce this:

```
{
    "OrganizationID": 1,
    "Loans": [{
        "Loan": "Test 001"
    }, {
        "Loan": "Test Loan 123"
    }, {
        "Loan": "Test Loan 234"
    }]
}
```

However, my requirement is to produce a *simple array of strings*, rather than an array of Loan objects.

Suggestions on how to shape the JSON would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON strings use `"` as the delimiter, not `'`. Also, we should take care of escaping (just in case). With those things in mind `JSON_QUERY` will help us out:

```
SELECT
    OrganizationID,
    JSON_QUERY((   
        SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(Loan, 'json') + '"', ',') + ']' 
        FROM Loan 
        WHERE Loan.OrganizationID = Organization.OrganizationID
    )) AS [Loans]
FROM Organization 
WHERE OrganizationID = 1
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```